# How to create effect that looks like an acetylene torch cut steel plate

Tags: modeling, edges, effects

I wanted to have some text cut out of a steel plate, but I wanted hot/glowing edges as if it has just been cut.

So far I did

1. Created a plane and bent/dented it with sculpting
2. Add a solidify modifier to give it some thickness
3. Created some text and extruded it
4. Overlapped the text with the plate and added a boolean modifier (which is applied) to cut out the text.
5. I applied a rusty metal material to the plate
6. I applied a shiny metal material to the cut faces in the plate.

Now I'm stuck trying to make the metal look like it was cut with a torch.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/212067/110840

Comment: Thanks I was fixated on the search for acetylene - should have search this SO for laser too